# How data dependency handled at cpu instructions pipeline parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, x86, cpu-architecture, multicore, instruction-set

I am trying to understand the instructions parallelism in case of multi-core or multiprocessor CPUs.

In a modern CPU typically contains more CPUs which can execute the Instructions parallel. These instructions  are stored in RAM and which is shared memory between the processors.

In case of instructions parallelism sometimes some instructions might have dependencies with previous instructions also called as data dependencies.

How this could be identified at CPU level to execute the data dependence instructions in sequentially?

Tried to understand the instructions parallelism of cpu but none of the books provides clear explanation about how this is handled at cpu instructions level.

Comment: In an out-of-order exec CPU (like all modern x86), the scheduler only considers instructions that have their inputs ready.  When an instruction completes, it writes a result to a physical register, and I think scheduler entries snoop that and match against the PRF numbers of their own inputs, or something like that.

Comment: But that's all instruction-level parallelism *within* one core.  Separate cores are independent, only interacting through memory via MESI cache-coherency.  (Usually with a tag directory to keep track of which core does or might own which line, instead of broadcasting all traffic from all cores.  e.g. Intel non-server CPUs use L3 tags for that, since it's inclusive and shared by all cores.)  If that's not what you're asking about, you should untag "multicore" at least, maybe also "parallel-processing" since ILP within one thread isn't what most people call "parallel processing".

Comment: In order to achieve parallelism within a single CPU, the CPU needs to be able to (1) fetch more than one instruction per cycle, and (2) execute more than one instruction per cycle, (3) retire more than one instruction per cycle.  As you're noting, when there are data dependencies, execution of some instructions must be delayed.  So, modern processors use queues and lists to buffer/delay instructions that are not yet ready to run.  You might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo's_algorithm, for the basic out of order processing, though advancements have been made since then.

Comment: Also, multi-core simply runs separate instruction streams, so there is no possibility of the same kind of data dependence between instruction streams / cores.

Comment: Further, if you're not familiar with simple 5-stage risc pipelines and how they handle data dependencies (forwarding/bypass), you might want to have a look into that (e.g. MIPS or ARM simple pipeline).

Comment: @ErikEidt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Data_hazards is fairly good if you want to point people at the basics for 5-stage RISCs, although it doesn't talk about implementation details like comparators for register numbers that were written by the last few instructions, comparing against inputs for current instructions to either stall or set up forwarding.  Speaking of basics, [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) is also excellent and discusses how dependencies limit parallelism. (but not true impl details)

Comment: Also related: [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350024) - it doesn't.  Each core in a multi-core CPU is superscalar, decoding and executing multiple instructions per cycle from a single thread, maintaining the illusion that they ran one at a time in program order.  (So yes, data dependencies do limit things.)